# Display Multiple Queryset in List View

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i'm trying to display multiple queryset with multiple models as a timeline  and sort em by time instead of displaying one queryset after the other my current code looks like that :

```
<div class="user-info col-md-8">
{% for obj in user.marks_set.all %}
                     <p>{{ obj.module }}</p> 
                      <p>{{ obj.grade }}</p>
                      <p>{{ obj.date }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% for obj in events %}
                      {{ obj.content }}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

all models have date field , i'm trying to display everything and order em by date instead of displaying all marks and after that all events

Comment: What problems are you facing ?

Comment: i'm trying to find a way to display em as a timeline  and order_by = "-date"  for example (mark ,event, mark) instead of displaying all marks after that all events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way i did it was using itertools chain and attrgetter

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import attrgetter

class MyListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs1 = Events.objects.all() #your first qs
        qs2 = Marks.objects.all()  #your second qs
        #you can add as many qs as you want
        queryset = sorted(chain(qs1,qs2),key=attrgetter('timestamp'),)
        return queryset
```

got the answer from this post [Combine 2 Django Querysets from Different Models](https://chriskief.com/2015/01/12/combine-2-django-querysets-from-different-models/)

### edit

```
#models.py
class Events(models.Model):
    ...
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True,)

class Marks(models.Model):

    ...
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True,)


#templates
 {% for item in queryset %}
 {% if item.anyfieldusniquetoqs1 %}
   #here goes all qs1 field you want to display
 {% else %}
   #here goes all qs2 field you want to display
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried your solution to my situation where two models are related by an FK relationship. Trying to use `attrgetter` using the FK field on the child model is raising **AttributeError: 'ParentTable' object has no attribute 'fk_field_childtable'**. How to approach this?

Comment: @LeLouch How do you use in the templates? Will you loop through the queryset? Can you give an example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @12379095 they are not related by FK they just have a common field called timestamp i've edited the answer you can check models.py

Answer (score 16):

Though not related to the core question, but since this answer shows up because of the title, so i am posting this for newbies:

> To return multiple querysets form a single ListView, if you can combine all the querysets in a single variable then it becomes acceptable in Django. The simple method would be to use a dict.

**For eg:** I need to fetch two queries from same Model, one is all the sellers and the other is top 5 sellers.
So in ***views.py:***

```
class ViewName(ListView):
    model = ModelName
    template_name = "seller_info.html"
    context_object_name = 'sellers'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = {'all_sellers': ModelName.objects.all(), 
                    'top_seller': ModelName.objects.all().filter(is_highest=True)[:5]}
        return queryset
```

In ***seller_info.html*** you can access each of these querysets by:

> For displaying all sellers:

```
{% if sellers %}
    {% for seller in sellers.all_sellers %}
      <p> {{ seller.name }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

> For displaying top_seller:

```
{% if sellers.top_seller %}
    {% for seller in sellers.top_seller %}
      <p> {{ seller.name }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Please note that if there is only one top seller then also use the above format of html but modify the queryset like: `'top_seller': ModelName.objects.all().filter(is_highest=True)[:1]`

Answer (score 4):

You could possibly zip all the querysets together. So if you override get_context_data and then say you had variables events and marks which contain a events querset and marks queryset, you could store those into one context variable. Then in the template you could put everything in a table and have a separate column for events and marks. This will put everything in order by their date, but they will just be in separate columns.

Views.py

```
class MyClass(ListView):
    get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        events = Events.objects.all().order_by('-date')
        marks = Marks.objects.all().order_by('-date')
        context['group'] = zip(events,marks)
        return context
```

template

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead">
        <tr>
            <th>Events</th>
            <th>Marks</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for events,marks in group %}
            <td>{{ events }}</td>
            <td>{{ marks }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```