# How to get books of the the same author in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am developing an online Book Store.
Here is the models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='authors')
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)   
    isbn13 = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    ...
```

Here is the View:

```
class AuthorsListView(ListView):
    model = Author
    context_object_name = 'authors_list'
    template_name = 'authors_list.html'
    paginate_by = 500

class AuthorBooksListView(ListView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'author_books'
    template_name = 'author_books.html'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        author_id = Author.objects.get(pk = self.kwargs['pk'])
        qs = super().get_queryset(**kwargs)
        return qs.filter(author = author_id)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet 
        context['author'] = Author.objects.get(pk = self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context

class PublishersListView(ListView):
    model = Publisher
    context_object_name = 'publishers_list'
    template_name = 'publishers_list.html'
    paginate_by = 500

class PublisherBooksListView(ListView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'publisher_books'
    template_name = 'publisher_books.html'
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        publisher_id = Publisher.objects.get(pk = self.kwargs['pk'])
        qs = super().get_queryset(**kwargs)
        return qs.filter(publisher = publisher_id)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet 
        context['publisher'] = Publisher.objects.get(pk = self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context

class BooksListView(ListView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'books_list'
    template_name = 'books_list.html'
    paginate_by = 100


class BookDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'book_detail.html'
```

Here is the urls:

```
    path('authors/', AuthorsListView.as_view(), name = 'authors_list'),
    path('author/<int:pk>/', AuthorBooksListView.as_view(), name='author_detail'),
    path('publishers/', PublishersListView.as_view(), name='publishers_list'),
    path('publisher/<int:pk>/', PublisherBooksListView.as_view(), name='publisher_detail'),
    path('', BooksListView.as_view(), name='books_list'),
    path('book/<int:pk>/', BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book_detail'),
```

On the Book Detail Page I want to display:

1. Related books by the same author
2. Related books by the same publisher
   How can I do this? Please help me.

I was trying to add these code to the BookDetailView:

```
    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        book = Book.objects.get(pk = self.kwargs['pk'])
        queryset = {
            'books': Book.objects.all(),
            'publisher_books': Book.objects.filter(publisher = book.publisher.id),
        }
            
        return queryset
```

But it gives me an error:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@djangodjarhes - Can you try the following? Ideally I modify the get_queryset if I want to change the way the queryset should be filtered other than the URL kwargs. For anything else, I override the get_context_data

```
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        book =  Book.objects.get(pk = self.kwargs['pk'])
        publisher_books = Book.objects.filter(publisher = book.publisher.id)
        context["publisher_books"] = publisher_books
        return context
```

In your case and feel free to correct me

```
 queryset = {
                'books': Book.objects.all(),
                'publisher_books': Book.objects.filter(publisher = book.publisher.id),
        }
```

This is not right. You are returning a dict when the get_queryset is supposed to return a queryset. You cannot return a dict. Either you change it to do this

```
queryset = Book.objects.filter(publisher = book.publisher.id)
return queryset
```

or use get_context_data if you want to return a dict.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
You tell "Ideally I modify the get_queryset if I want to change the way the queryset should be filtered other than the URL kwargs" 
So, how can I modify the get_queryset in my case?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer helped me very much.

Comment: Concerning "You are returning a dict when the get_queryset is supposed to return a queryset": I read about this solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48872380/display-multiple-queryset-in-list-view Answer by Pran Kumar Sarkar. As I understand - this is not correct? then how can I get multiple querysets if I need?

Comment: And one more question. Publisher books works fine. But how can I get Author books? Authors in my model are many-to-many field. So I cannot use Book.objects.filter(author = book.author.id)? Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @djangodjames- get_queryset can only return one model queryset not multiple. Not multiple. If you need additional queryset to be passed to your template then use the get_context_data() and override it and add it in the queryset you want in your context dictionary.

Comment: @djangodjames- I think many to many fields filtering work differently. If an author has a field book which is a m2m field then first filter out the author from the Author model e.g author = Author.objects.get(id='something')...then to access the books you can use author.books_set.all()... Depends on if you have a related_name in your M2M field.